# Cpanel Mailing List

Tags: joomla, cpanel, mailing-list

I am using Mailing list provided by Cpanel for my website made in joomla. I want a submit button on home page with a field to enter the email address. I want the email address to be automatically added to the mailing list on clicking the submit button. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that you mean PHPList, which has several extensions that integrate it with Joomla at various levels. It looks like most of the extensions are commercial, so you might want to try option #2. Take a look here for the extensions -

http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=phplist

The other option is to use Chronoforms to make a subscribe form. You can find instructions on how to do that here - http://www.jessekanclerz.com/blog/2008/02/how-to-integrate-a-phplist-subscribe-page-into-joomla/ and here http://www.chronoengine.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4717&start=0